Partial plot with scroll bar when using `vertical_layout: scroll` with `flexdashboard` and `runtime: shiny`
I am trying to present a basic plot inside flexdashboard with runtime: shiny. That works fine with the flexdashboard default, vertical_layout: fill, but not with vertical_layout: scroll, where the plot is partially hidden and I cannot figure out how to make the container box (not the plot) higher so as to show the full plot. Why add a scrollbar if the plot doesn't use the entire screen space? Reprex:

---
title: "Minimal Flexdashboard Example"
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows   
    vertical_layout: scroll
runtime: shiny
---

## Row 1 {data-height=800}

```{r}
ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plot", height = "500px")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot(plot(1:5))
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```


Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/452

What you're doing or attempting to do is run a shiny app inside of a webpage. If you were running a flexdashboard with runtime shiny, you wouldn't call for a ui or server, instead you add runtime: shiny in the YAML. Check out this resource to learn more.

@Kat oops, you are right, on the image it was with runtime: shiny and it will only work with that, somehow I removed it when copying the example. I corrected it now, thanks! Of course, the display issue is still present then

I wish I could give you a built-in method to solve the issue, but I could only come up with a workaround.
This adds CSS controls for the Shiny iframe.
There are 2 layouts that happen behind the scenes (I'm assuming these are from Flexdashboard)

'desktop-layout' --apparently assigned based on screen size

in this mode, it appears that Flexdashboard's containers are doing what you would expect in terms of vertical fill
Shiny's iframe is not filling the space it's given - ignoring its parent container


'mobile-layout' class

Flexdashboard's response: vertical fill? I don't care what you want, you're getting vertical scroll.
Shiny's response: I still really don't care what my parent container is doing. I will be whatever size I want. (You don't own me Flexdashboard.)



This should fix your issue though:
---
title: "Minimal Flexdashboard Example"
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows   
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

<!-- based on screen size....? -->
<style>
div.desktop-layout * iframe.shiny-frame {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
div.mobile-layout * iframe.shiny-frame {
  height: 500px;
}
</style>

## Row 1 {data-height=800}

```{r shinier}
ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plot", height = "500px")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot(plot(1:5))
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Taaa daaaa!

In desktop layout:

In mobile layout:


Wow, it works wonderfully, amazing! Good explanations too : -) I'm surprised it requires that much css code to fix what seems like a basic feature. I wonder whether you should also share this solution on the GitHub issue? (I can also do it if you prefer)

I've added what worked here to the Github issue. Glad I was able to help.
